# MySQL InnoDB table accepts Non-Existent Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key, mysql-5.6

Using EasyPHP 14.1 VC11 and phpMyAdmin (4.1.4) to create a website project in my home computer. The MySQL version is 5.6.15 according to the EasyPHP administration page.

Working on Windows 7 64-bit.

---

I've created the tables I needed and specified each foreign key in the "Relation view" (on Structure tab). All the tables are InnoDB and the default engine is set to InnoDB.

---

Assuming I have the tables `A` and `B`, and `B` has a foreign key to the column `ID` of the table `A`.

When inserting a line in table `B`, if I write 0 (zero) on the foreign key column and submit, it accepts.

In the Browse tab it shows the line with the foreign key column with the value 0 (zero).

When I click on the value (link to the that line on the table `A`), I go to that table with zero results.

---

In the variables tab, the "`foreign key checks`" variable is "`ON`".

But the foreign keys are not checked or the insert would fail since there is no `ID` 0 on table `A`. What have I done wrong or forget?

---

> Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable\G` for both table A and table
>   B and post it in the question. –  RolandoMySQLDBA

Table A

```
CREATE TABLE `competicaogeral` (
 `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Nome` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Nome` (`Nome`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Table B

```
CREATE TABLE `competicao` (
 `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Nome` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
 `CompeticaoGeral_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Nome` (`Nome`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable\G` for both table A and table B and post it in the question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that the `FOREIGN KEY` is in the table design of your table B.

## EXAMPLE

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
    StaffID INT NOT NULL,
    ProjectName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Allocation INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StaffID, ProjectName) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff(StaffID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

## Facts

- Table A is the table `Staff`
- Table B is the table `projects`
- `FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff(StaffID) ON DELETE CASCADE` requires `StaffID` in `projects` to reference a row in `Staff` with the same `StaffID`

## Your Original Question

```
CREATE TABLE `competicao` (
 `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Nome` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
 `CompeticaoGeral_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Nome` (`Nome`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

You need a foreign key reference

```
CREATE TABLE `competicao` (
 `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Nome` varchar(190) NOT NULL,
 `CompeticaoGeral_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Nome` (`Nome`),
 FOREIGN KEY (CompeticaoGeral_ID) REFERENCES competicaogeral(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

The SQL to do this would be

```
ALTER TABLE competicao ADD FOREIGN KEY (CompeticaoGeral_ID)
REFERENCES competicaogeral(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: It doesn't appear on Create Table like you said. But I've set it on "Relation view" in phpMyAdmin. I'll try creating the table using a sql query. How can I set the foreign key without a SQL query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It worked. SQL shows the 1452 error for the ID 0. Thank you for the answered. It seems that the Relation view is not what I'm thinking or is working wrong.